# How do session time out and and ask for login again in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-restcontroller, spring-session

I am trying to build simple JSON rest API using spring boot, I have build the application it works fine, now I need to do the simple Basic authentication and I did this with Spring security. Please find the Code below, My pain point here is when I run the application, I ask for the login first time then I tried to reload the URL again it does not ask for user name password. How to make the URL session expired and ask to prompt for login again. **Note :**  I am not using any UI, It just an API

**Security Configuration Class**

```
package com.erplogic.erp.topcon.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistry;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz.anyRequest().authenticated()

        ).sessionManagement(session -> session
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
                )
        
        .httpBasic();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User.builder().username("user").password(encoder().encode("pass")).roles("USER").build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {

        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }
}
```

**Controller Class**

```
package com.erplogic.erp.topcon.controller;

import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.erplogic.erp.topcon.service.SapApiService;
import com.erplogic.poc.objects.Root;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;

import io.erplogic.maven.plclog.wsdl2java.StandardFaultMessage_Exception;

@RestController
public class OutboundController {
    @Autowired
    private SapApiService sapApiService;

    
    @RequestMapping(path ="/outbound",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Root getOutbound() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, StandardFaultMessage_Exception, JsonProcessingException {
        
        return ((SapApiService) sapApiService).processOutboudService();
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/outbound/{outboundId}",produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getOutboundId(@PathVariable String outboundId) throws KeyManagementException, JsonProcessingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, StandardFaultMessage_Exception {
        
        
        return ((SapApiService) sapApiService).processOutboudServiceByID(outboundId);
    }

}
```

Comment: does `sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)`  satisfy your requirements?

Comment: No, I added the code   @Bean
  SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http
             .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                 .anyRequest().authenticated()
                 
             )
             .sessionManagement(session -> session
                     .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
                 )
             .httpBasic();
         return http.build();
     }

Comment: Please do not write code in comments it unreadable. Update your question

Comment: ok, I will update in question

Comment: If you are using Basic Authentication, you may find that the server is requesting auth again, but that the browser is sending the previously entered credentials automatically.